# join user and follower table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, join

I have user table and follow  table 
in follow table I have user id - and - follower id

I have to make list where I have to take email id of user and follower

how can I join both table

```
select f.USER_ID ,a.user_firstname, a.user_email ,f.Follow_Id 
from bb_follow f, bb_user a 
where a.user_id = f.User_Id and f.Active_Status=1 order by f.User_Id asc
```

( now I want info of follower - how I can add ) –

Comment: I tried this now from same user table I have to add follower first name and email id

Comment: follow table ( user id ,followId, IsActive) user table ( user id,First name , emailid) - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Join the **bb_user** table twice, aliasing as **a** (for user) and **b** (for follower).

```
select f.USER_ID, a.user_firstname, a.user_email,
      f.FOLLOW_ID, b.user_firstname as follower_firstname, b.user_email as follower_email
from  bb_follow f, bb_user a, bb_user b 
where a.user_id = f.User_Id
and   b.user_id = f.Follow_Id
and   f.Active_Status=1
```

or with ANSI joins:

```
select f.USER_ID, a.user_firstname, a.user_email,
      f.FOLLOW_ID, b.user_firstname as follower_firstname, b.user_email as follower_email
from  bb_follow f
      join bb_user a on a.user_id = f.User_Id
      join bb_user b on b.user_id = f.Follow_Id
where f.Active_Status=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT f.USER_ID, a.user_firstname userName, a.user_email userEmail, 
       f.Follow_Id, b.user_firstname followerName, b.user_email followerEmail
FROM bb_follow f
LEFT JOIN bb_user a ON a.user_id = f.User_Id 
LEFT JOIN bb_user b ON b.user_id = f.Follow_Id 
WHERE f.Active_Status=1 
ORDER BY f.User_Id ASC;
```

Answer (score -1):

Heres an overall for you, the syntax iswrong, you need to JOIN ON

SELECT * FROM bb_follow f,
JOIN bb_user a
ON f.User_id = a.user_id 
WHERE f.Active_Status = '1'

Try that, then add your specific values